# TimescaleDB's drop_chunks Statement doesn't drop accurate timed chunks

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using a TimescaleDB and want to get rid of the old data.

As test purposes I am filling an empty Hyptertable with some different data.

I ran the following statement with 2 hours old data, 10 hours old data and
15 hours old data:

```
select drop_chunks(interval '1 hours', 'my_table')
```

Only the 15 hours old data gets deleted. By reading
https://docs.timescale.com/v1.1/api#drop_chunks
I would assume all data should be droped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

drop_chunks only drops full chunks. if your chunk_time_interval is set at something like 12 hours, timescaledb will only drop full 12 hour chunks.

Comment: the chunk_time_interval is set to 24h. So you are completely right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let me clarify Diana's comment:  Every chunk is defined by a bounding box; for time, you can think of these as `start_time` and `end_time`.   If you specify something like:

`select drop_chunks(interval '1 hours', 'my_table')`

This says to drop all chunks whose `end_time` is more than 1 hour ago.  So my guess from your above example is that your 15 hour data was in one chunk, but your 2- and 10-hour data was in another chunk with an `end_time > now() - 1 hour`.

To see the time bounds of your chunks and other information:

`SELECT * FROM chunk_relation_size_pretty('my_table');`

(On review, I can see where the docs are a little unclear here; I've updated the instructions:  https://github.com/timescale/docs.timescale.com-content/pull/86 )